# Push ViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, push, pushviewcontroller, linphone

I have added UINavigationBar in appDelegate method. Please check my atatched screen shots. In bottom is i have used UINavigationBar. In middel of the page history button is there.

Here when i click the history button its cant go to historyviwcontrooler. Because i cant push the view. Can you please tell me how i can push here. When i click history its called only one calls after only thet called another class there only i given UI. How i handel here . please help me

```
#import "UICallButton.h"
#import "LinphoneManager.h"

#import <CoreTelephony/CTCallCenter.h>

@implementation UICallButton

@synthesize addressField;


#pragma mark - Lifecycle Functions

- (void)initUICallButton {
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self initUICallButton];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self initUICallButton];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
    if (self) {
        [self initUICallButton];
    }
    return self;
}   

- (void)dealloc {
    [addressField release];

    [super dealloc];
}


#pragma mark -

- (void)touchUp:(id) sender {


    NSString *address = [addressField text];
    NSString *displayName = nil;
    ABRecordRef contact = [[[LinphoneManager instance] fastAddressBook] getContact:address];
    if(contact) {
        displayName = [FastAddressBook getContactDisplayName:contact];
    }
    [[LinphoneManager instance] call:address displayName:displayName transfer:FALSE];

}

@end
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: i attached image view is homeViewControlled but when i click the history its call to UICallButton.m

Comment: The code you pasted has nothing to do with pushing a a view controller

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you must have a `UINavigationController`, and not just a `UINavigationBar`, in order to be able to perform a push transition to one `UIViewController` to another.

I'm not explaining how to do that because it's very basic, you should study and read some books/tutorials before begin a real project.

Here's some links to help you:

1. [A nice tutorial](http://www.idev101.com/learn/navigation_controllers.html)
2. [How to use navigation controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html) (from apple)
3. [Navigation Controller class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Yes Lucas Eduardo. But My home page only i have used UINavigationController. When i click its not called any UIViewController. Its called one class after its called TPMultiLayoutViewController. thats y i cant where i put pushview controller without Navigation Controller.